# Session state when laptop battery dies while using private/incognito mode of browser

Tags: browser, private-browsing

If I'm using the privacy mode of a web browser and the battery dies, what happens to my session?

I haven't got my charger and the laptop just died on me.

When I turn it back on will I be able to access my previous session?

Answer (score 3):

Your computer has probably gone to Hibernate, in which case your private browsing session will still be available when you resume (to the browser, nothing has changed - it has been suspended in its current state).

Answer (score 1):

If it hasn't gone to hibernate, your session is lost.